# MAC OS X Mavericks 10.9.0 installation on VMWare Sphere Client 5.1

Tags: macos, vmware, login-screen

i want to test something on mac os x ([Open VPN](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/installation-guide-for-openvpn-connect-client-on-macos/)) and because i do n't have this os in my local machine i decided to install it on my dedicated server.
so i created a virtual machine on vmware sphere client 5.1 and installed mac using with it's iso file.
after installation i stucked on this page :

[image: Mac OS X Login Page]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/hdMHDy.png))</sub>

this is my first time installation of mac os x and i really do n't know what is that user name and password?
during installation i did n't create any user name and password and i think there should be a default user/pass like some linux os's. for example **root and toor** or something like them.

## question #1 : what is that user name and password?

that image was from **open console** of vmware virtual machine in **one of vps's** in vmware and my big problem is i can not move mouse in this login page.
i really do n't know what is going on in this page for mouse move, but i can not touch apple logo or users logo with mouse.
also when i tried to use keyboard i only can switch between user name and password textboxes.

## question #2 : how can i move mouse in this login page with keyboard or another way?

## question #3 : what is your suggestion and how can i enter mac os x in my situation?

i can not open this console in my local machine becaouse my internet speed has problem to showing this login page and this is why i am using one of my vps's.

would be really appreciate to help me about that....

Comment: One question per question is the best for the site. Glad someone got you the answer you needed, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the username is : admin

Password is : admin

Well, actually if this doesn't work a lot of times do not type in nothing, or you can type in "guest" as the username and password. Guest works for me. Sometimes writing nothing also works for me.

---

I think you should use an external mouse or another mouse and use a Mac mouse for example the mighty mouse or something like that because you are using a Mac Machine / VM.

---

My suggestion is that you should follow the steps I provided because, you never know, this might actually work out.

---

## Notice :

If you think I posted something wrong on this topic or you need to edit / suggest something please leave a reply.

Comment: both user name and password : admin -> FAILED

Comment: both user name and password : guest -> FAILED

Comment: both user name and password : blank -> FAILED | Any other idea?

Comment: Hmm. Did you download the copy from apple or from a website?

Comment: Because, if you did. The copy, the owner of the copy has the password, contact him.

Answer (score -2):

Username: root     Password: niresh